# Description Resource Path Location Type cvc-complex-type.2.4

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

hey guys when i write the tag  in the applicationContext.xml i got error"Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'" from eclipse i dont know why.

this is the applicationConext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="dao" class="org.gestion.bp.dao.BanqueDaoImp"></bean>
<bean id="metier" class="org.gestion.bp.metier.BanqueMetierImp"></bean>
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
<bean id="metier" class="org.gestion.bp.metier.BanqueMetierImp"></bean>
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</beans>
```

You have closed the 'bean' with `</bean>` **before** the property. It should be:

```
<bean id="metier" class="org.gestion.bp.metier.BanqueMetierImp">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```